# Do you have to kill people in a private online game?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Can I play the game without killing anyone?

If I started a private online game by myself would I still need to kill people?

I can't play any violent games, all I want to do is free roam on a motorcycle and go to the shooting range in the game, but I don't want to kill.

Answer (score 3):

You don't *"have to"* kill people, but the game is designed to make it *very easy* to kill people. Say you're driving down the road, your motorcycle hits a corner too hard and careens into the sidewalk running over pedestrians. Boom you've accidentally killed people, their blood on your hands.

The entire game will make killing people nearly unavoidable as time goes on, even if you only play the multiplayer, but by no means are you forced to do so.

Comment: In Story mode, you have to.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Hence why I address his question "in a private online game", and mention "even if you only play the multiplayer".

Comment: Ok thanks... but what if I drive normal, like I don't go crazy with my EPIC driving skills (just joking). How graphic is it when it comes to sexual content (not in story mode)? And is there a way to turn off/mute bad language?

Comment: Rephrase the last sentence to `If you play only the multiplayer are you not forced to.` instead. Not the entire game makes it unavoidable to kill.

Answer (score 1):

Killing people is completely avoidable in GTA Online if you want to play the game that way but you will obviously be limited in the content you can take part in, since the game is about heists and murder. There is even a "passive mode" in GTA Online which specifically prevents you from pulling out a weapon or being harmed by the actions of others (it won't stop you driving over people, though).

If you want to play GTA just to drive around and admire Los Santos, there is nothing stopping you from doing that, even in single player mode (once you're past the initial few story missions).

Comment: thank you so much! this is by far the better question, but is there a way to turn off/mute bad language? how graphic is it when it comes to sexual content in online only?

Comment: in both online and offline (excluding story mode) you have to actively look for the sexual content (excluding the radio stations, which can just be turned off). Voice comms can be completely disabled, haven't checked if you can disable chat...

Comment: can u maybe expand on that a bit more please? like what do u mean I have to actively look for sexual content?

Comment: I mean that there are strip clubs and hookers in the game, and if you don't enter the strip clubs and you don't pay the hookers you avoid all of that content

Comment: ok but in passive mode does it make me less likely to run into any graphic content?

Comment: No passive mode makes you invulnerable to other players and prevents you from punching/kicking others or pulling out a weapon. It does not change any of the content in the game as such (so Online other people will still be shooting at each other in the street as you drive around), stop you from running into/driving over people, or stop you from being the target of aggressive actions from NPC players (ie if you carjack somebody and they get angry, they'll punch you but you won't be able to punch back due to passive mode)

Comment: one other thing, when u first start online u have the race and then the part after that that includes killing is there a way to skip that mission with the killing?

Comment: I'm unsure - you may be able to drive off and ignore the mission, you may be able to fail the mission enough times to skip it (like in single player, not sure if this is actually an option in multi-player), if not then probably no other solution than to complete the mission

Comment: shoot... ok thanks then, I might try that if I get the game :) thanks for all your help

Comment: ok I found a video on YouTube on how to skip the killing mission. hopefully it might work

Comment: @EmeraldKIng202 Listen guy, I applaud the effort your putting into this, but this really needs to be said, so since nobody else did, I'll say it. If your looking for a non-violent, non-graphic, non-vulgar gameplay experience, GTA V is the wrong game to be playing.

Comment: I suspect the question might be posed as a parent wanting to play and not have to do so after the kids go to bed.

Comment: not to be sassy but ender please do let me know what kind of game that has first person, infinite possibilities for your character, cars/trucks/motorcycles, open world, and free roam? because so far this one takes the cake... and plus that's all I want in a game... all I need is all that stuff I listed and then its a perfect game for me

Comment: Infinite possibilities, apart from murder, theft and bad language? Maybe there's a gap in the market for a Middle Class Sunday Driving Simulator :)